# How to put one or several package files into a changelog in sql format

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

in a changelogfile (in sql mode), I want to update or create severals package.
I don't want to write all the package in 1 file.
I want to be able to do a rollback.

How can I do it ?

the oracle command "@" is not recognized.

thanks

Michel

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, it is the [Include](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/include.html) tag you are looking for.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd">

    <changeSet id="a_changeset" author="a_developer">

       <comment>Doing some stuff</comment>
       ...

    </changeSet>

    <include file="someMoreChangeSets.xml" />

</xml?
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't use your solution because I only use sql file (myfile.sql)

I think it's not the better solution to use sql files, but I don't want to totally change "How the developpers code"

thanks

Michel